# Initialize class variable just once - objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, initialization

So I've been trying to get a variable in my class (TrackViewController) initialize just once.
This is done to keep the inserted id from the database known to the viewcontroller.

In short:

I have a TrackManager which receives a location update through a NSNotificationCenter.
The TrackViewController uses the startTracking method when a button is clicked.
The function is set in my TrackManager and returns the id of the newly inserted row in the database.

This id should be kept by the TrackViewController so that when I go back to my main screen of my application and then get back to the TrackViewController it still knows this id. This is needed to call the method stopTrack:(long)trackID to stop tracking locations for that track and set the database column "TrackFinished" to finished.

I thought to solve this using static variables but I'd rather not.

Is there a way to initialize a variable just once in TrackViewController.
I've tried awakeFromNib, ViewDidLoad, and such but those methods are called every time I get to the TrackViewController screen.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried initWithCoder and initWithFrame?

Comment: Checking into the initWithCoder. This might solve it. I'll get back to you.

Comment: If you do one, you need to copy and paste the same thing into the other, as initWithCoder is called when initialised from a NIB/XIB, and initWithFrame is called when initialising without a NIB/XIB.

Comment: I don't seem to get it encoded. It says I encoded value 5 (for instance) but when I decode it just gets back to 0.

Comment: @Tikkes Old question, but from the description it sounds like you are trying to solve the problem architecturally in the wrong place. It would be better to have a "currentTrackID" property on your TrackManager that the TrackViewController can access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting something like this in your viewDidLoad method, or initMethod. Of course replacing NSObject with whatever type your variable is.

```
static dispatch_once_t pred;
static NSObject *shared = nil;
dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    shared = [[NSObject alloc] init];
});
```

Another approach is to check whether the variable is already allocated:

```
if (!variable)
    variable = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

Comment: This uses static variables and I'd rather not have those.

Comment: Replace it with a non-static variable. I just pulled this example from one of my projects.

Comment: If you'll be using a local variable, it'll run every time. If you'll be using an instance variable, it'll run once per instance. But there's no way of making it run once per class, like you asked, without static variables.

Comment: Okay, I'm using the static variable then anyhow. Thanks for the help guys! Much appreciated